# Google App Engine: Get entity key to use in a template

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Assuming I have the following:

```
class Person(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
```

I would like to print all the names in an html file using a template.

```
template_values = {'list': Person.all()}
```

And the template will look like this:

```
{% for person in list %}
<form>
  <p>{{ person.name}} </p>
  <button type="button" name="**{{ person.id }}**">Delete!</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Ideally I would like to use person.key or person.id to then be able to delete the record using the key but that doesn't seem to work. Any Ideas how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in one of the code samples:

```
template_values = {'list': **list**(Person.all())}
```

And in the template:

```
{% for person in list %}
<form>
  <p>{{ person.name}}</p>
  <button type="button" name="**{{ person.key }}**">Delete!</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

As Wooble recommended, you may want to try Person.all().fetch(SOME_NUMBER) instead.

Comment: list(Blah.all()) is an anti-pattern - it'll fetch results in batches of 20. .fetch() is always the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Use `{{person.key.id}}`, not just `{{id}}`.  This will call each object's `.key().id()` method(s).

However, you should also be aware that passing `Person.all()` as a template value isn't necessarily a great idea; `.all()` returns a `db.Query` object, which can be treated as an iterable like you're doing but which will do multiple RPCs as you iterate through the query; instead you should use something like `Person.all().fetch(SOME_NUMBER)`, where SOME_NUMBER is a reasonable amount to display to the user (or an arbitrarily large number if you insist on trying to display everything in one view.)

Comment: Hi I tried person.id as I mentioned in the question (last sentence) but it returned an empty string. I edited the name of variable to avoid confusion.

Comment: edited; you need .key().id(); id() isn't a method of the entity at all.